# Umbraco temporary page

Tags: asp.net, umbraco

I was building an Umbraco 7.4.3 site, and I was ended up to this situation.
I have a node structure inside Umbraco like this.

[image: Example]

So, I have a Student and Teacher node under Home.

The Student node will show a detail about student.

Now I want to have a page where I can edit a Student, "I want a separate page (not popup) linking to a page where I can edit a student", something like a /edit-student/?id=2.

But in order do that I will end up in a structure like this, see screenshot

[image: Example]

See? I have an extra node EditStudent just to have a page where I can edit student, I can call this page by /Student/EditStudent/?id=2

But I don't want to have this node "EditStudent", I feel it was making my node structure dirty.

**I want a solution that** I can still have a url like this /Student/EditStudent/?id=2 but I don't want to see a node "EditStudent" under Student or somewhere else inside my Umbraco.

Is this possible to happen? something like a virtual url (but not aspx) pages.

Comment: You could always use an MVC route to do this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the answer I posted at our.umbraco.org forum.

Just create a template and Ill name it as "Edit", then you can access like this url: /Student/Edit/, and of course you can add parameters.

If there is no other node name "Edit" found under Student then it will use "Edit" template as alternative.